# Referencing two of the same document from another document in Mongoid

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I am trying to store messages and I want to store to and from User reference as below:

```
class Message
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :from, type: Moped::BSON::ObjectId
  field :to, type: Moped::BSON::ObjectId
end

class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :username, type: String
end
```

Is the above the correct way of doing so? I can imagine one way is to create User as a custom type, but that seems a lengthy direction to take. Ideally I want to be able to reference the User directly as so: `message.from.username` or `message.from['username']` and be able to validate the presence of the from and to fields.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Message
  belongs_to :from, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: nil
  belongs_to :to, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: nil

...
Message.where(from: my_user)
```

Comment: What is `inverse_of`? I'm guessing you would put the same but with `has_many` in `User`?

Comment: The mongoid document will attempt to "magically" get the relationships working for you.  IE  A -> B and B -> A.  However, sometimes, you don't want the relationship to shared on both sides.  So, you use inverse_of: nil to indicate that there is no reciprocal relationship.  This is abuse of the macro. :)